# How not find out why R is not stopping running

Tags: r

I am running a *CompetingRiskFrailtySurvfitCreat*e function from the "CompetingRiskFrailty" Package in R. The example works well. But when I tried out my own data, it stuck. I don't know whether it is still running and need more time or is there an endless loop? Is there any way to find out what is going on?

Thanks in advance!!

There are the first 20 obs of my data. And I got 3034 obs in total

```
    X1  X2  X3  X4 X5 X6 X7 X8  X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15
1  101 140  0  0  0  1  1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0
2   401 421  0  0  1  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0
3   601 519  0  0  0  0  1  0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
4   602 349  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
5   701 111  0  1  0  0  0  1 NaN   1   0   0   0   0   0
6   701 488  0  1  0  0  0  1 NaN   1   0   0   0   0   0
7   701 488  0  1  0  0  0  1 NaN   1   0   0   0   0   0
8   702 614  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0
9   702 614  0  0  0  1  1  1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
10 1001 362  0  0  1  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0
11 1001 362  0  0  1  0  0  0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
12 1001 362  0  0  1  1  1  0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
13 1002 204  0  0  1  0  1  1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
14 1002 204  0  0  1  0  1  1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
15 1002 204  0  0  1  1  1  0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
16 1002 204  0  0  1  1  1  1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
17 1101  51  0  0  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
18 1201 789  0  0  1  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0
19 1202 328  0  0  1  0  0  1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0
20 1202 328  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
```

The following it my code:

```
    ID <- D_u$X1
    surv.time <- D_u$X2
    status <- cbind(D_u$X3, D_u$X4, D_u$X5)
    my.Surv <-  CompetingRiskFrailtySurv(ID=ID,surv.time=surv.time,status=status)
    my.Survfit <- CompetingRiskFrailtySurvfitCreate(my.Surv ~ X6 + X7 + X8 + X9 + X10 + X11 + X12 + X13 + X14 + X15, data = D_u , risk.names=c("N","N without S","D without N"))
```

Comment: "Is there any way to find out what is going on?"
Yes, there is a way. Please post your code and example data. Also, how large is your data?

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question. The example dataset is 500 obs and even if I tried the first 500 obs of my data, R still stuck with the first estimate

Comment: That package was removed from CRAN and is only in the Archives. Last version of this package was posted 26-Nov-2007. Seems unlikely that it would run with anything like a current version of R.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah, You are right, I downloaded the archived code and built a package with his codes. His example works, though.